# Bad State: No ProviderScope found

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting this error:

Bad state: No ProviderScope found

I get this error when I try to load my Booking Screen.

In my main.dart I have already added this line of code. But still, this error keeps popping up.

```
runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
```

Can someone suggest what else should I check?

Comment: It might be that you simply need to fully restart your app after adding that line, as in stop the process entirely and run it again. If that doesn't work, it would be helpful to post code for a minimum reproducible example of your problem

Comment: @MichaelHorn okay I will try to fully restart my app

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

It means you installed [`riverpod`](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod) instead of [`flutter_riverpod`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod) ...